# Using box2dlights in libgdx, render font underneath shapes but not be affected by lights or shadows

Tags: libgdx, box2d

My goal is to have my font drawn underneath my level shapes, but not be affected by the lights. Currently they're underneath but shadows block parts of the text.

Any ideas?

inside my `render()` method ..

```
// draw fps on screen
game.getBatch().begin();
game.getFont().draw(
    game.getBatch(), 
    String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()), 
    25.0f, 
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
game.getBatch().end();

// draw level shapes and draw lights
getLevel().draw();
```

Heres my `Level.draw()` implementation ..

```
public void draw(){

    world.step(1.0f / 60.0f, 8, 1);
    world.getBodies(bodies);

    for (Body body : bodies) {

        ((Shape) body.getUserData()).draw();
    }

    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera);
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();
}
```

Comment: If you are doing `getLevel().draw()` after your you do your `game.getFont().draw()`, wouldn't it definitely make your shadows appear on top of the text? Try moving the getLevel.draw() before your first batch call.

Comment: @chongdashu then the shapes would also be on top of the Font...

Comment: What you want to do is pretty hard. A possible solution is to render the shadows/lights, then render the font and then render the shapes. But i guess, then the shapes won't be affected by the shadows anymore. But i guess it's worth a try...

Comment: @Springrbua your solution does not work. shapes are not affected by the lights/shadows.

Comment: @bobbyrne01 yea i thought so. Another try: Render the shapes + lights/shadow to a FrameBuffer and then render the FrameBuffer on top of the Font. I guess the shadows will still affect the Font, but its worth a try...